# Local minimum value of a two variable function.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $f(x,y)=4xy-x^{3}y-xy^{3},(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^{2}.$ Then the value of $f$ at a local minimum in the rectangular region $R=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^{2}:|x|<\frac{3}{2},|y|<\frac{3}{2}\}$ is

$A.$$-2.$

$B.$$-3.$

$C.$$-\frac{7}{8}.$

$D.$$0.$

Actually its objective type question and have to solve within 3 minutes so i want some direct trick that gives very quickly answer. Thanks a lot.

Comment: If this is on your prep, I expect that this is one of those tests where you're not actually expected to get every question, and this is only really meant for those who'll have longer than three minutes by the time they get to this question, or who are fast enough to do it in three minutes using partials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the derivative of $f(x,y)$ w.r.t $x$ to zero gives:
$$3x^2 + y^2 = 4$$
Setting the derivative of $f(x,y)$ w.r.t $y$ to zero gives:
$$3y^2 + x^2 = 4$$
Solving for $(x,y)$ gives 4 critical points: $(-1,-1)$, $(-1, +1)$, $(+1,-1)$, $(+1,+1)$.

Now since you got 3 min, you could just start trying, you get that $f(1,1) = f(-1,-1) = 2$ and $(f(-1,1) = f(1,-1) = -2)$ so $-2$ is your answer.

P.S:If you are required to prove it, then you would have to look at the sign of $f_{xx}f_{yy} - f_{xy}^2$ where $f_{xy}$ is the double derivative w.r.t $x$ and $y$.